# Не срабатывает BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcast-receiver, android-camera

Приложение должно включать вспышку на 3 секунды при входящем смс,но не включает)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Camera camera;
boolean isFlashOn;
boolean hasFlash;
Camera.Parameters params;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Проверяем поддержку работы с фонариком на устройстве:
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    if (!hasFlash) {
        //Если вспышка не поддерживается, показываем
        //диалоговое окно с ошибкой и закрываем приложение:
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Ошибка");
        alert.setMessage("Ваше устройство не поддерживает работу со вспышкой!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Закрываем приложение:
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }
    getCamera();


}
//Получаем параметры камеры:
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Ошибка, невозможно запустить: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
//Включаем вспышку
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

    }

}
//Выключаем фонарик
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;
    }
}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //Получаем для приложения параметры камеры:
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    //Закрываем работу камеры:
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                turnOnFlash();
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    turnOffFlash();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }
}
}
```

Манифест http://pastebin.com/uBr6C2Uq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maxim.smsled" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: пастбин у некоторых заблокирован, так что выкладывайте манифест в теле вопроса.

Comment: И уточните - вы не получаете интент о приходе смс или фонарь не включается когда интент пришёл?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не получаю интент

Comment: Скопируйте манифест в вопрос и уточните как вы поняли, что интент не пришёл? Пробовали в onReceive в логи что-то вывести и при приходе смс логи оказались пусты?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пробовал,не проходит

Comment: см. ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469625/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло(

Comment: `receiver ` должен быть внутри тега `application`

Comment: @metalurgus не помогло

Comment: @maxim, это для начала. Без этого не будет вообще работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно комменту @metalurgus:

> receiver должен быть внутри тега application

---

Судя по всему проблема у вас в том, что класс `IncomingSms` объявлен у вас в одном файле с активити, а не в отдельном.

Также проверьте в каком пакете он лежит и напишите в манифесте полный путь к файлу ресивера вместо `.IncomingSms`

и попробуйте добавить ещё разрешение на чтение смс в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Неудивительно, что не срабатывает, если делать так, как вы написали, то ресивер сработает только, если вы его [зарегистрируете в Activity методом **registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), но будьте внимательно, регистрацию нужно снимать в методе onPause, а регистрировать в методе onStart. Если же работать через манифест, то тогда регистрируете его в манифесте и создаёте отдельный класс